# TypeError: Required argument 'dest' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a shooter game with pygame, but when I run my game, it displays the pygame window, but gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nnamdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\game.py", line 26, in <module>
  SCREEN.blit(text)
TypeError: Required argument 'dest' (pos 2) not found
```

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

ammo = "10" # you have ten ammo, use it wisely...

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption('Bomber')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
DARKBLUE = (2, 9, 129)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 255)

SCREEN.fill(DARKBLUE)
pygame.display.flip()
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
text = basicfont.render('Bomber', True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
SCREEN.blit(text, dest)
is_running = True
while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

Hopefully, you can help.

Comment: Can you give us the whole error?

Comment: what is `dest`?

Comment: Line 26 in your error [`SCREEN.blit(text)`] and line 26 in the code you have posted [`SCREEN.blit(text, dest)`] are (currently) clearly different.  Which makes one of them incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the `dest` variable. You should also call the function `pygame.display.flip()`. For example:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

ammo = "10" # you have ten ammo, use it wisely...

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption('Bomber')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
DARKBLUE = (2, 9, 129)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 255)

SCREEN.fill(DARKBLUE)
pygame.display.flip()
basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
text = basicfont.render('Bomber', True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
dest = (100, 100)
is_running = True
while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False

    SCREEN.blit(text, dest)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @LillyM. update my solution